# send data lwip STM32 PC

Tags: c++, c, qt, embedded

I am trying to send or receive data from STM32f(via raw lwip) to computer.
I connected stm32f device to modem and send "ping" and it is ok.dhcp in lwip have got the ip number from modem.And I would like to use QT Creature to send data to STM32 via lwip(connected modem).I dont know what my port number is.What will I write in this codes as port number.

Could you offer me a way,what will I do.
Also, is it possible if I connect the stm32f device directly to computer and communication?

```
tcpSocket->connectToHost(QHostAddress("192.168.1.30"),portnumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the value you put in the `tcp_bind` function call? This should be the port you are listening on. It would be best if you would use a port over 1024 because of the privileged access needed on normal systems with operating systems.